# Can I run a shell command from python script in the current shell

Tags: python, shell

I have a python script which invokes two different shell scripts. The first script sets some environment variables which are required by the second script. The python code has the following structure :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["bash", "a.sh"]) #a.sh sets env_var1
subprocess.call(["bash", "b.sh"]) #b.sh reads env_var1
```

Because the scripts `a.sh` and `b.sh` run in different shells, the above code does not do the needful.
I want to know that can we execute these shell scripts from python in the current shell itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to execute shell script in the same process in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621193/how-to-execute-shell-script-in-the-same-process-in-python).  Short answer: seems like you can't.  The workaround is to merge your scripts and run it in one process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run multiple commands synchronously from one subprocess.Popen command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721924/how-to-run-multiple-commands-synchronously-from-one-subprocess-popen-command)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line to run commands to your shell in python  `os.system('command to run here')`

In your case it would be something like:

```
import os

os.system('./a.sh')
os.system('./b.sh')
```

Comment: but how do I run both scripts in one `os.system`

Comment: the os.system doesn't leave the current shell, so running the one after the other will ensure the environment variables are created in the first script and accessible in the second

Comment: yes out of python it works. Following is my python script `path1 = r'd1/xyz.csh'
path2 = r'd2/abc.csh'
os.system("cat d1/xyz.csh")
os.system(path1)
os.system("echo $Env_var_1 sys1")
os.system(path2)`.  And `xyz.csh` is `Env_var_1="var one by xyz"
Env_var_2="var two by xyz"
echo $Env_var_1`. And `abc.csh` is `echo $Env_var_2, "in abc"`

Comment: use export when creating the variable

Comment: export also didnt help

Comment: I don't know the issue, `os.system` works the same as typing out the commands on the terminal. maybe try replicate the sequence you used on terminal with several os.system lines. Otherwise sorry I don't know

Comment: The issue is that `os.system` in fact does spawn a subprocess in which the subshell runs. It does so for every call to `os.system` which means you get a "fresh" process/subshell every time. Just try `os.system("export MYVAR=someval; echo $MYVAR")` and then `os.system("echo $MYVAR")`, or simply consecutive calls to `os.system("echo $$")`.

Comment: I'm not a python person, but does `os.system('./a.sh;./b.sh');` get you anything usable (assuming `export`ed var definitions in `./a.sh`).? Good luck to all.

Comment: Or `os.system('source ./a.sh; b.sh');` ?